# How do I set bitset for a variable with the an integer name

Tags: c++, bitset

I want to set the bitset of the char '0' equal to 0101010101 but when I try I get the error "expected an identifier"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>
using namespace std;
int main() {
bitset<8> '0'=0101010101;
}
```

I've also tried

```
bitset <8> 0(string("0101010101"));
```

but I get the same error

Comment: Identifiers cannot start with a digit. What you're trying to do is not possible in C++.

Comment: *"I want to set the bitset of the char '0' equal to 0101010101"* That makes no sense. Are you trying to change what `'0'` means using some kind of reflection-like feature? That's not possible, and certainly not with `std::bitset`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `unordered_map` to set one to one mapping between an int and a bitset. The length of the sample `0101010101` is 10 so size of bitset will be 10 and `0101010101` = `341` in decimal.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <bitset>

std::unordered_map<int, std::bitset<10>> M {
    {0, 341},
    {1, ...},
    ...
    ...
    ...
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << M[0] << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`0` is an int literal and `'0'` is a char literal, neither of which are variable names.
You can use `_0` as variable name. Or even better use a name that describes what the  variable is used for.